# Split pandas Series into contiguous chunks by index value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to split a Series into sections where each section is contiguous and has the same index. So for this input:

```
df = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], index=[1,1,1,2,2,1,1])
```

The desired result would be three chunks like:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]
```

I was attempting to use `groupby` but that groups the [1,2,3] and the [6,7] into one section which is not desired since they aren't contiguous:

```
>>> groups = list(df.groupby(df.index, sort=False))
>>> len(groups)
2
```

Can this be done in Pandas (or Numpy)?

Comment: You can use numpy `split` function: `result = np.split(df.values, np.diff(df.index.values).nonzero()[0]+1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could

```
In [761]: [v.tolist() for _, v in df.groupby(df.index.to_series().diff().ne(0).cumsum())]
Out[761]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

---

Details

Get consequent chunks.

```
In [762]: df.index.to_series().diff().ne(0).cumsum()
Out[762]:
1    1
1    1
1    1
2    2
2    2
1    3
1    3
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn your series into a dataframe and then use `groupby` with `shift` + `cumsum`:

```
df = df.reset_index()

group_key = (df['index'] != df['index'].shift()).cumsum()
res = df.groupby(group_key)[0].apply(list).values.tolist()

print(res)

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

`group_key` enumerates groups of values:

```
print(group_key)

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
Name: index, dtype: int32
```